# Unit testing a method with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to learn how to do Unit testing with C# and Moq, and I've built a little test situation. Given this code:

```
public interface IUser
{

    int CalculateAge();
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    public int CalculateAge()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year;
    }
}
```

I want to test the method `CalculateAge()`. To do this, I thought I should try giving a default value to the `DateOfBirth` property by doing this in my test method:

```
var userMock = new Mock<IUser>();
userMock.SetupProperty(u => u.DateOfBirth, new DateTime(1990, 3, 25)); //Is this supposed to give a default value for the property DateOfBirth ?
Assert.AreEqual(22, userMock.Object.CalculateAge());
```

But when It comes to the assertion, the value of `CalculateAge()` equals 0, although `DateOfBirth` equals `new DateTime(1990, 3, 25)`.

I know this may look like a silly example, but whatever... I thought I could use mocking to give values to not-yet-developed method/properties in my objects, so the testing of a method wouldn't depend on another component of my class, or even setting up a default context for my object (hence the name of the user here...) Am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: *Really* nice article that aligns in parallel with your question: http://kakimotonline.com/2011/01/02/unit-testing-net-application-with-moq-framework/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you approaching it wrong, but don't worry, I'll explain why. First hint would be

> you can completely remove your `User` class and everything will be the
>   same.

When you are doing:

```
var userMock = new Mock<IUser>();
```

You just creating a fake\mock object of that interface, that has nothing to do with your initial `User` class, so it doesn't have any implementation of `CalculateAge` method, except of fake one that just silly returns 0. That's why you are getting 0 in your assert statement.

So, you were saying:

> thought I could use mocking to give values to not-yet-developed
>   method/properties in my objects, so the testing of a method wouldn't
>   depend on another component of my class

You could, let's say you will have some consumer of your IUser, lets say like the following:

```
class ConsumerOfIUser
{
   public int Consume(IUser user)
   {
      return user.CalculateAge() + 10;
   }
}
```

in that case mocking of IUser will make total sense, since you want to test how your `ConsumerOfIUser` behaves when IUser.CalculateAge() returns 10. You would do the following:

```
var userMock = new Mock<IUser>();
userMock.Setup(u => u.CalculateAge()).Returns(10);

var consumer = new ConsumerOfIUser();
var result = consumer.Consume(userMock);

Assert.AreEqual(result, 20); //should be true
```

Comment: So there's absolutely no reason to use Mocking while testing a class alone? By alone I mean that there's no interaction with other classes. For example, let's say I had a method that downloads a bunch of things, and that takes 10 minutes to run. And that CalculateAge() uses a value returned by this method... Would it be useful to Mock this result? (Let's say DateOfBirth were that 10mins downloading method, instead of just an auto-property)

Comment: @Pacane, that's right. Testing a class without external dependencies (in its purest form) should not require a mock or a stub.

Comment: The method to download stuff should be written in another class, which can be mocked out for testing.

Comment: Pacane, yes it would make sence, but you should to make that property that takes 10 minutes to be an external component, so your current class can depent on it, so you will be able to mock it.

Comment: So if I want to test CalculateAge(), I should instantiate a User in a test context, and assert the result based on the DateOfBirth I have initially set in my object, instead of using the mocks..

Comment: @seldon, I know this topic is old, but I am also trying to get started with Moq. So, it makes sense to unit test my ICustomerRepository interface, correct? Because ICustomerRepository simply contains a list of contracts only.  However, if a concrete class that uses ICustomerRepository, that's when we will use Moq to mock this repository. Did I get it? Thanks.

Comment: @Stack0verflow, something along those lines, yes. Testing an interface by itself doesn't really make much sense as there's no logic involved. What you might want to test there is just the composition of that interface from another class, that it's being passed the appropriate data etc. Otherwise I think you're spot on.

Comment: Thanks, @seldon.  Can someone edit my comment above? I really meant it makes no sense to unit test my ICustomerRepository interface, where the "no" is missing in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your trying to test. In this case, you have mocked out the User object, so there is no point in testing anything inside this class as you are replacing it with a mock object. If you want to test the User object then you shouldn't mock it out.

Mocks are used to replace dependant objects that you don't want to test. For example, if you had a Name object instead of a string (e.g contains first name, surname, title etc..) but you didn't want to test the Name object, just the User object, you would create a mock of the Name object to be used when constructing the User object.